# Interpret dispersion parameter in gamma GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, dispersion

On p. 383, Fox writes that "[with a gamma GLM] the dispersion parameter is simply the inverse of the shape parameter." I am trying to understand for what distribution this applies to.   Using an intercept only model (see first analysis below) it seems that we are modeling the distribution of Y.  But when I add a very strong predictor, that is no longer true.  So I would like to what distribution is the dispersion parameter modeling?

```r
    #example
    n = 10000
    set.seed(0)
    y = sort(rgamma(n, 5, .25))
    
    ###intercept only
    fit.0 = glm(y~1,Gamma)
    var(y)
    mean(fitted(fit.0))^2*summary(fit.0)$dispersion  
1/summary(fit.0)$dispersion                      
    
    ###add predictor that is not too strongly related to the 
      #response
    x = runif(n, 1, 9)
    fit.1 = glm(y~x,Gamma)
    summary(fit.1)
    var(y)
    mean(fitted(fit.1))^2*summary(fit.1)$dispersion   
1/summary(fit.1)$dispersion                       
    
    ## sort x so that the relationship is now very strong, 
    ## I can no longer
    ## compute variance from dispersion
    
    x = sort(runif(n, 1, 9))
    fit.2 = glm(y~x,Gamma)
    summary(fit.2)
    var(y)
    mean(fitted(fit.2))^2*summary(fit.2)$dispersion 
1/summary(fit.2)$dispersion
```